# Verwendung von „brauchen“ als Modalverb und „bräuchte“

Tags: verb, usage

Als ich beim Forschen war, um mehr über den Konjunktiv II zu lernen, um ein Handout zu machen, habe ich in *Hammer’s German Grammar and Usage* gelesen, dass *brauchen* manchmal als ein starkes Verb verwendet wird (davon hatte ich nie zuvor gehört):

> Das bräuchte ich, um die Aufgabe zu lösen.

Ich wusste bereits, dass es manchmal als Modalverb benutzt wird:

> Wir brauchen das Haus nicht aufräumen.

Wie üblich sind diese Verwendungen? Würden solche Verwendungen unangenehm auffallen, wenn man sie beim Sprechen benutzt? Wie ist es in der Schriftsprache?

Comment: "Wir brauchen das Haus aufräumen" ist insofern falsch das 'brauchen' in dieser Form ausschließlich in negierter Form verwendet wird. Ich hab das bei meinem Edit deiner Frage direkt berüchsichtigt.

Comment: @Em1 aber du hast die Partikel *zu* hinzugefügt. Dann ist das Verb nicht mehr modal, oder?

Comment: @c.p. Zitat des Tages: Wer brauchen ohne zu gebraucht, braucht brauchen gar nicht zu gebrauchen.

Comment: @Em1 :) schön, ich glaube, ich stimme zu, dass *brauchen* ein *zu* braucht. Jedoch geht die Frage um das Gegenteil, und zwar dass *brauchen* manchmal als Modalverb verwendet wird. Wo ist denn das *modales* Merkmal? Man sagt  „Wir {können·müssen·wollen·sollen…} das Haus nicht aufräumen“ (ohne zu). Ich dachte ein  Kriterion wäre, dass Modalverben kein *zu* bräuchten.

Comment: @c.p. Es gibt tatsächlich die Tendenz in der gesprochenen Sprache das "zu" mehr und mehr fallen zu lassen. Der Grammatik-Hinweis des Dudens bzgl. *brauchen* im Sinne von *müssen* lautet aber: "mit Infinitiv mit »zu«; verneint oder eingeschränkt". Das liegt daran, dass *brauchen* eigentlich **gar kein Modalverb ist**, häufig aber solches verwendet wird und 'neuerdings' oft auch als eines betrachtet wird (ja, die Zeitangabe ist sehr unspezifisch).

Comment: Ich brauche mehr Details.

Comment: verwandt mit *ought to*, oder *achten*? Englisch *need be* drängt sich auch im Vergleich auf, noch mehr Französisch *a besoin de* "benötige".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Brauchen* is quite commonly used as both a main verb and a kind of modal acting verb. But it’s not a modal verb. According to the [Wortschatz-Portal](https://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en) its use (including both types) is just as often as the verb *laufen*. In spoken language, you will encounter this word very often, too, in any of the following definitions.

The [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/brauchen) lists three definition for the main verb:

1. benötigen (e.g. *Ich brauche Geld*, *Ruhe brauchen*, *Hilfe brauchen*, *Zeit brauchen*)
2. benutzen (e.g. *Brauchst du die Sachen noch?*)
3. verbrauchen (e.g. *wenig Strom brauchen*, *wenig Platz brauchen*)

The forth definition covers the modal use in the sense of *müssen*. Remember: It’s used in negation and for restriction only. Some common examples:

> Du brauchst nicht zu kommen. [= Du musst nicht kommen.]
>   Du brauchst mir nichts zu erklären. [= Du musst mir nichts erklären.]
>   Du brauchst mich gar nicht so anzusehen. [= Du musst mich nicht so ansehen.]
>   Du brauchst es nur zu sagen. [= Du musst es nur sagen.]

You definitely cannot replace *müssen* with *brauchen* in the opposite way. You can take the German counterpart of *have to* instead:

> Du hast zu gehorchen. [= Du musst gehorchen.]

Finally, I’d like to repeat something based on a [comment of c.p.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8782/verwendung-von-brauchen-als-modalverb-und-br%C3%A4uchte#comment23015_8782):

> Ich dachte ein Kriterion wäre, dass Modalverben kein *zu* bräuchten.

This statement is true! ***Brauchen* is not a modal verb**. It's usage is just quite similar to modal verbs and it [‘behaves’ like a modal verb](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/VollHilfModal/Andere.html?lang=en&darj=1). It’s even possible to drop the *zu*. This is restricted to colloquial though. For that reason, *brauchen* is often mentioned when talking about modal verbs.

Comment: This answer was really helpful! How common is the "umgangssprachlich" usage of brauchen as a pseudo-modal Verb (w/o the meaning of "nicht müssen") and the use of bräuchte- as the subjunctive 2?

Comment: @thekeyofgb "nicht brauchen" as 'pseudo-modal verb' does always carry the meaning of "nicht müssen". Regarding the subjunctive: in the corpora the "brauchte" occurs ~3 times more often than "bräuchte". I cannot give any numbers about spoken language but the only use case I can think of off the top of my head is "Ich bräuchte [=benötigen] noch etwas mehr" when you do not have enough of something (whatever that may be: Geld, Zeit, Material) - [Here](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=22&Wort_id=780267&bl=208) are examples for the online occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

*Brauchen* ist zunächst einmal ein ganz normales Verb, dessen Konjunktiv 2 mit Umlaut gebildet wird.

> Ich brauche etwas.
> I need something.
>
> Ich brauchte etwas.
> I needed something (past).
>
> Ich bräuchte etwas. = Ich würde etwas brauchen.
> I’d need something/I needed something (cond.)

Es wird auch hier und da modalverbhaft verwendet, aber nur, wie @Em1 im Kommentar schon festgestellt hat, wenn ein *nicht* dabei steht.

> Du brauchst nicht anrufen.

Das ist ganz ähnlich, wie English *to need*

> You need not call.

Aber

> You need **to** call.

Comment: "to need" kann auf English im Positiven modal gebraucht werden: "I need to go", "you need to paint your house".

Comment: Ein schwaches Verb mit Umlaut im Konjunktiv, aber „ganz normal“? Scheint mir ein Widerspruch in sich. Dieser Aspekt ist behandelt in http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10900