# Wann fungiert "brauchen" als Modalverb?

Tags: modal-verb

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/VollHilfModal/Andere.html?darj=1) kennt einige Verben, welche ähnlich zu Modalverben verwendet werden können:

> Neben den Modalverben dürfen, können, mögen, müssen, sollen und wollen gibt es noch ein paar andere Verben, die in ähnlicher Weise eine Modalität angeben können. Sie werden mit einem Infinitiv mit zu kombiniert.

Als Beispiel nennen sie mehrere Verben, die ich im Rahmen dieser Frage aber ausschließen möchte. Ich beziehe mich nur auf das Verb *brauchen*, welches zum einen das häufigste dieser Verben ist (in dieser Funktion) und zum anderen auch ohne "zu" angewendet wird/werden kann.

```
brauchen (mit nicht, nur, erst u. Ä.)  
    Du brauchst nicht mehr zu kommen. = Du musst nicht mehr kommen.
```

In einer [Diskussion mit Emanuel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11791/discussion-between-em1-and-emanuel), basierend auf der Frage [Verwendung von “brauchen” als Modalverb und “bräuchte-”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8782/verwendung-von-brauchen-als-modalverb-und-br%C3%A4uchte), habe ich festgestellt, dass es anscheinend nicht eindeutig ist, wann genau *brauchen* nun als Modalverb fungiert und wann nicht.

Unter anderem ist dieser Satz gefallen:

> [Emanuel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12452104#12452104): Modalhafter Gebrauch liegt für mich nur dann vor, wenn KEIN "zu" im Satz ist.

Wie eingangs bereits erwähnt, ist die Verwendung von *brauchen* ohne "zu" sehr gängig. Daher ist der Satz

> Du brauchst nicht anrufen.

nicht nur häufig anzutreffen, sondern meines Erachtens sogar akzeptabel. Zugegeben, ich würde unter Umständen das sogar selbst so sagen.

In den allermeisten Fällen würde ich jedoch stets zu dem Wörtchen "zu" greifen.

> Du brauchst nicht so laut zu schreien.
>   Du brauchst nicht sauberzumachen.

Während ich in den beiden vorherigen Sätzen es nicht anmakeln würde, wenn jemand diese ohne "zu" verwendet, wäre es in meinen Augen in den folgenden Beispielen falsch:

> Du brauchst es nur zu sagen.
>   Du brauchst kein Clown zu sein, um Witze zu machen.

Hierzu der Standpunkt von [Emanuel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12452096#12452096):

> Aber das ist doch kein modaler Gebrauch.

Ich indes denke, dass es hier die gleiche Funktion hat, wie *müssen*:

> Du musst es nur sagen.
>   Du musst kein Clown sein, um Witze zu machen.

Wann schlüpft denn nun *brauchen* in die Rolle eines Modalverbs und wann ist es einfach nur das ganz normale Verb?

---

Möglicherweise stark verbunden: [Suggeriert “brauchen” unterschiedliche Aussagen, wenn es als Pseudo-Modalverb verwendet wird?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/suggeriert-brauchen-unterschiedliche-aussagen-wenn-es-als-pseudo-modalverb-ve)

Comment: @Emanuel Siehe auch meine zweite Frage zu dem Thema: [Suggeriert “brauchen” unterschiedliche Aussagen, wenn es als Pseudo-Modalverb verwendet wird?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8791/1224).

Answer (score 3):

Dein erstes Zitat sagt es: "brauchen" ist nie ein Modalverb. Deshalb benötigt es das "zu", wenn es doch eine Modalität ausdrücken soll. Die Beispiele, bei denen Du meinst, das "zu" könne weggelassen werden, empfinde ich als schlicht falsch. Trotzdem hört man sie zum Beispiel hier in Berlin.

Answer (score 1):

**It does not.**

I think it differentiates German from e. g. Polish, Swedish and Russian.

Nobody would say

> Ich brauche jetzt angenehm sitzen.
>   Brauchst du schon schlafen?
>   or
>   Wir brauchen viel trinken bei der Hitze.