# Suggeriert "brauchen" unterschiedliche Aussagen, wenn es als Pseudo-Modalverb verwendet wird?

Tags: word-usage, connotation, modal-verb

Zusätzlich zur Frage [Wann fungiert “brauchen” als Modalverb?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/8789/1224) eine weitere. Wie dort erwähnt, ist es für mich in manchen Fällen akzeptabel, das "zu" fallen zu lassen, während ich in anderen dies als grenzwertig oder gar falsch ansehe.

Nun habe ich mich gefragt, woher das kommt. Dabei ist mir dann aufgefallen, dass bestimmte Sätze, die ich eingangs als falsch empfand, nach öfterer Wiederholung doch ganz OK klangen. Meine Vermutung ist, dass hier Kontext eine große Rolle spielt.

Als Beispiel habe ich mal einen Kontext um den Satz "Du brauchst nicht anrufen." mit verschiedenen Intentionen (K1–K3) konstruiert:

> Kind: Das hat die Lehrerin aber so gesagt.
>   Mutter: Das glaube ich nicht. Da frage ich mal nach.
>   K1/K2: Die brauchst du nicht an(zu)rufen. Die hat das wirklich gesagt. [=*Tue das nicht, ich lüge nämlich.* oder *Du kannst es machen, wenn du magst, aber es ist unnötig, weil es wirklich stimmt.*]
>   K3: Die brauchst du nicht an(zu)rufen, denn sie ist jetzt nicht mehr in der Schule. [=*Es ist absolut egal, ob du es machst.*]

Ein Beispiel mit einer anderen Handlung, aber gleicher Unterscheidung:

> A: Ich fahre nach Hause. Ich rufe dich an, wenn ich dort angekommen bin.
>   B1: Du brauchst mich nicht an(zu)rufen, ich mache mir schon keine Sorgen.
>   B2: Du brauchst mich nicht an(zu)rufen, ich bin dann nämlich gar nicht da.

Meiner Meinung nach handelt es sich hier so oder so um einen modalen Gebrauch [=Du musst nicht]. Der Unterschied ist aber, dass im letzteren Fall jeweils die Aktion gar nicht ausführbar ist (zumindest nicht vollendet werden kann), während der erste bzw. die ersten beiden eine Auswirkung auf die Personen haben wird/werden.

Nun meine Fragen dazu:

Ist der Kontext entscheidend, ob die Verwendung von "zu" hier zwingend notwendig oder schlicht falsch ist? Oder ist dies absolut irrelevant?
Verändert sich unter Umständen durch das Einfügen von "zu" unterbewusst die Intention des Satzes? Sprich, kann man die Begründung danach sogar weglassen, ohne missverstanden zu werden?

Oder ist es sogar so, dass (bedingt durch Intention) es sich in einem Fall um den modalen Gebrauch handelt, im anderen Fall aber das "normale" Verb Anwendung findet (-> "Du brauchst nicht versuchen, mich anzurufen [=Es benötigt keinen Anruf], weil ich gar nicht da sein werde)?

Ergänzung:
Die Antwort von c.p. auf die Parallelfrage hat mich auf etwas aufmerksam gemacht, was mir beim Schreiben der Frage entgangen ist. Da es semantisch hier besser aufgehoben ist, ergänze ich es an dieser Stelle.

Das schlichte Hinzufügen eines Adverbs kann schon die Satzaussage dermaßen ändern:

In zwei Sätzen stecken vier Aussagen. Da die Aussagen C1 und C2 auch verschmolzen werden können, könnte ich aus dem bloßen Satz heraus keine Aussage herauskristallisieren. Bei C3 und C4 würde ich aber den Satz je nach Aussage mal mit als auch mal ohne "zu" bilden:

> - C1: Du brauchst nicht (zu) kommen, wenn du nicht willst.
> - C2: Du brauchst nicht (zu) kommen. Wir schaffen das auch ohne dich.
> - C1 + C2: Du brauchst nicht (zu) kommen, wenn du nicht willst. Wir schaffen das auch ohne dich.
> - C3: Du brauchst nicht mehr zu kommen, da wir fertig sind. Aber du kannst, wenn du möchtest. Wir sind noch hier.
> - C4: Du brauchst nicht mehr kommen, da wir fertig sind. Und wir gehen jetzt weg.

Wie seht ihr das?

---

Gerade beim nochmaligen Durchlesen bemerkt: In dieser Frage habe ich zufällig ein sehr interessantes Beispiel verwendet: "Du brauchst nicht versuchen, mich anzurufen".
Hier ist es meiner Meinung nach **kein** modaler Gebrauch, da es nicht die Funktion von *müssen* hat [≠Du musst nicht versuchen, mich anzurufen -> imho klingt das im Kontext sogar sehr komisch]. Es beschreibt hier (wieder) nur die 'Überflüssigkeit' einer Aktion, weil sie fehlschlagen wird. Es ist somit kongruent mit den Beispielen K3 und B2 aus dem obigen Abschnitt.

Lustigerweise schreibe ich es hier sogar spontan ohne "zu" und nicht "Du brauchst nicht zu versuchen, mich anzurufen." – Bin mal auf die Antworten und Kommentare gespannt...

Comment: Sher interessante Frage... ich hatte auch einen kurzen Moment wo ich überlegt habe "Moment mal! Ist brauche nicht zu und brauche nicht eigentlich das gleiche?" aber ich hab's dann verdrängt :)

Comment: Ich habe diese Webseite (http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/verb-brauchen/) gefunden, und darauf steht es, dass "brauchen" ohne "zu" standardsprachlich "nicht müssen" bedeutet. Es wird dazu hinzugefügt, dass brauchen ohne "zu" wird umgangssprachlich verwendet.

Comment: @thekeyofgb... ja, die Frage ist ob es genau Deckungsgleich ist oder nicht. Etwa so wie "you must not" vs "you're not allowed to". Im groben ist es gleich, aber in den Nuancen vielleicht nicht (bin kein Muttersprachler, kann's also nicht sagen)

Comment: Gefühlt macht das "zu" in deinen Beispielen keinen Unterschied in der Interpretation. Weder "Du brauchst mich nicht anrufen", noch "Du brauchst mich nicht anzurufen" enthält eine Implikation über den Grund. Die Aussage ist also: "Ein Anruf ist nicht notwendig, aber wenn du unbedingt willst, kannst du es machen". Das "versuchen" dagegen ändert die Bedeutung komplett, weil hier impliziert wird, dass die Aktion fehlschlagen wird. Ohne Kontext kann das leicht interpretiert werden als "Du brauchst nicht versuchen mich anzurufen, weil ich nicht abnehmen werde, wenn ich deine Nummer sehe".

Comment: http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/bgsl.1996.1996.issue-118/bgsl.1996.1996.118.393/bgsl.1996.1996.118.393.xml ... hab's nicht gelesen, leider (zu teuer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kurz gesagt ist es durch deinen Idiolekt begründet, inhaltliche Unterschiede zu sehen zwischen brauchen mit zu und ohne. Es gibt aber eigentlich keinen Unterschied, d. h., es ist egal, der Sinn des Satzes ändert sich gar nicht. Es gibt auch keine Nuancen. Umgangssprachlich wird *zu* oft weggelassen, ohne dass das etwas ändert, schriftlich sollte man es aber benutzen (siehe auch [hier](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/verb-brauchen/)).

Answer (score 0):

Die Schule bringt Schülern bei, dass brauchen immer noch mit "zu + Infinitiv konstruiert wird. Aber die Leute halten sich einfach nicht daran, weil brauchen als Modalverb empfunden wird. Vielleicht sollte die Schule ihre Taktik ändern und beides zulassen. Ausschlaggebend ist letztlich wie die Leute sprechen und so manche Regel hinkt der Entwicklung hinterher. Und in vielen Fällen haben die Leute das bessere Empfinden als die Grammatiker.

Hier wird das Problem brauchen als Modalverb angesprochen, aber man ist noch sehr zögerlich und meint, standardsprachlich müsse man immer noch zu verwenden. Es wird aber darauf hingewiesen, dass sich die Umgangssprache nicht darum schert.

http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/verb-brauchen/