# Warum erscheint der Konjunktiv II für „kommen“ als „käme“, während der Konjunktiv für „brauchen“ keinen Umlaut hat?

Tags: subjunctive

Schauen Sie sich bitte ruhig die zu den Verben [*kommen*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/kommen_%28Konjugation%29) und [*brauchen*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/brauchen_%28Konjugation%29) entsprechenden Konjugationstabellen und merken Sie sich bitte die Verben in folgendem Tempus:

```
  Präteritum, Aktiv, Konjunktiv II für die 1. Person.
```

Laut den Tabellen entspricht dem ersten Verb *ich käme*, dem zweiten aber *ich brauchte*. Ich erwartete –wie ich oft höre– *ich bräuchte*:

- Warum in aller Welt erscheint da *brauchte* ohne Umlaut? D. h. gibt es wesentlichen Unterschied zwischen beiden Verben? Ich glaube *brauchen* ist ebenso „modal“ wie *kommen* ([oder?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/wann-fungiert-brauchen-als-modalverb)).

---

Hinweis: Der Ursprung dieser Frage ist ein gescheiterter Versuch, den Konjunktiv für *machen* als „ich *mächte* gerne …“ zu bilden.

Comment: Schöne Frage! Regional, bzw. umgangssprachlich gibt es [bräuchte](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/brauchen) nämlich schon.

Comment: Siehe auch http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/br%C3%A4uchte - Ich (aus Süddeutschland) wäre gar nicht auf die Idee gekommen, im Konjunktiv brauchte zu verwenden.

Comment: Googelt man etwas, findet man: *brauchte* ist „richtig” (Danke für die Frage, ich war mir dessen nicht bewusst), *bräuchte* wird auch in der Hochsprache häufiger, und natürlich [beklagen](http://sprachkreis-deutsch.ch/2010/03/14/3313/) das einige.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm.. dito. Bin aus Berlin. "brauchte" klingt literarisch für mich.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... das ist alerdings eine Schweizer Seite, es geht also um Schweizer Deutsch. Wenn das für die "abscheulich" klingt, so sei es. Mit meiner Realität (100% bräuchte) hat das nix zu tun.

Comment: @Emanuel, Danke für den Hinweis, das war mir nicht aufgefallen. Ich hatte aber auch noch ähnliche Seiten gefunden (nur mit weniger Entrüstung), und ich sehe auch keinen Grund für die Annahme, dass sich Schweizer Hochdeutsch in diesem Punkt vom deutschen Standarddeutsch unterscheidet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sieht man mal vom Konjunktiv II ab, ist *brauchen* ein schwaches Verb und es im Konjunktiv II nicht zu beugen ist daher durchaus naheliegend, da konsistent. Die Form *bräuchte* ist also hochgradig irregulär und erstmal genauso überraschend und befremdlich, wie es *mächte* wäre.

Unter dieser Prämisse, stellt sich dann eher die umgedrehte Frage: Wieso ist *bräuchte* so verbreitet und erscheint uns sogar intuitiv richtig? Hierüber kann ich (wie auch jeder andere) nur spekulieren. Folgendes erscheint mir aber recht plausibel:

- *Brauchen* wird häufig verwendet, um andere Verben zu modifizieren:

  > Ich brauche nicht (zu) rennen.

  Muss eine derartiger Satz noch mit einem weiteren Hilfsverb versehen werden, wie in der *würde*-Form für den Irrealis, wird es hässlich:

  > Ich würde nicht so rennen (zu) brauchen, wenn ich früher losgegangen wäre.

  Also verwendet man in solchen Fällen bevorzugt den Konjunktiv II. Bei *brauchen* wäre die reguläre Form *brauchte* aber mit dem Imperfekt identisch und es ergäben sich die üblichen Verwechslungsprobleme. Dieses Problem wird vermieden, wenn man *brauchen* im Konjunktiv II irregulärerweise zu *bräuchte* beugt.
- Etwas Ähnliches passiert beim Konjunktiv II der Höflichkeit, der auch ein häufiger Anwendungsfall des Verbs *brauchen* ist: Dieser wird ja nicht durch die *würde*-Form ersetzt (niemand sagt: »Würde ich bitte ein Kilo Hackfleisch haben können.«), aber bei der ungebeugten Konjunktiv-II-Form *(brauchte)* ergibt sich wieder ein Mehrdeutigkeitsproblem.

  Statt einer der folgenden Konstruktionen:

  > Ich brauchte ein Kilo Hackfleisch.
  >   Ich würde ein Kilo Hackfleisch brauchen.

  nutzt man also

  > Ich bräuchte ein Kilo Hackfleisch.

Comment: Vielleicht auch wegen "gebräuchlich"... oder "die Bräuche". Das gibt's bei "machen" zwar auch "mächtig", "Mächte" aber da ist die VErbindung weniger offensichtlich

Comment: @Emanuel: Das war sicherlich nicht hinderlich, aber alleine hätte es nicht gereicht – sonst *lächten, gläubten* und *käuften* wir heute (wegen *Gelächter, lächerlich, gläubig, Käufer,* …).

Comment: könntest auch einfach in historische Texte schauen, wenn da was zu finden ist, brauchste nich zu spekulieren. Aber wer will das schon.

Comment: @vectory: Und was würde ich dort finden? Hat irgendwer dokumentiert, warum sich die Grammatik so entwickelt hat, wie sie es tat?

Comment: habe falsch punktuiert. "Wenn da was zu finden ist, brauchste nich zu spekulieren". Betonung liegt auf *wenn*. Was wir dort also finden würden? Darüber kann man wohl nur spekulieren.

Answer (score 3):

Sprache verändert sich. Manchmal gehen starke und irreguläre Formen verloren, weil sie nicht oft genug benötigt werden, manchmal werden neue erzeugt, um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden.

Der reguläre Konjunktiv II von *brauchen* ist identisch zum Indikativ, was wegen des häufigen Gebrauchs problematisch ist. Die *würde*-Form ist hässlich bei modifizierenden Verben, da man schnell bei drei Verben im Satz landet.

Obwohl Umlaute ursprünglich nichts mit dem Konjunktiv oder auch Plural zu tun hatten, werden sie heutzutage gern als Marker dafür benutzt. (vgl. auch *Vogel*, dessen Plural war einst auch einfach *Vogel*, nicht *Vögel*)

Comment: Schöne Ergänzung zu Wrzlprmfts Antwort.

Answer (score 2):

Die Tabellen sind nicht up-to-date. Da werden einfach alte Tabellen nachgedruckt. Regelrecht wäre der Konjunktiv brauchte, formgleich mit Indikativ, da brauchen regelmäßig ist. Die Leute haben aber längst erkannt, dass bei einem so häufig gebrauchtem Verb wie brauchen ein schwacher Konjunktiv nichts taugt und sagen bräuchte, was viel klarer ist. Du müßtest deine Tabellen also ergänzen und anmerken: In Umgagssprache bräuchte.