# "brauchen + Infinitv"

Tags: difference

Soweit ich weiß, benutzt man das Verb "brauchen" mit "zu + Inf",

> Das brauchst du nicht **zu** tun.

In der Umgangssprache sehe ich jedoch immer mehr die Variante ohne "zu". Z.B:

> Ich brauche ihm keine Fragen stellen. /Quelle: Facebook/

Ist das ein Fehler oder eine alternative Variante, die nur umgangssprachlich gebräuchlich ist?

Comment: [This](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8782/verwendung-von-brauchen-als-modalverb-und-br%C3%A4uchte) more or less answers your question I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eine der schönsten Regeln der deutschen Sprache und Stilistik heißt:

> Wer *brauchen* ohne *zu* gebraucht, braucht *brauchen* gar nicht zu gebrauchen.

Dieser Regel folgend ist die umgangssprachliche Verwendung von *brauchen* ohne *zu* in der Tat ein Fehler.

Ein ordentlicher Schullehrer und ein gewissenhafter Zeitungsredakteur würden einen solchen Satzbau im Aufsatz des Schülers oder Artikel des freien Mitarbeiters auch sofort anstreichen.

Im Alltag hat sich *brauchen* ohne *zu* jedoch in der Tat so weit verbreitet, dass vermutlich ein großer Teil der deutschsprechenden Bevölkerung gar nicht mehr in der Lage ist, dies als Fehler oder auch nur als unschön zu erkennen.

Ob 'Fehler', 'häßlich' oder 'umgangssprachliche Variante' - entscheide selbst!

Leitend für deine Entscheidungsfindung sollte der Kontext sein: Im Kneipengespräch: wurscht. Im Zeitungsartikel: igitt! Im Bewerbungsschreiben: konservativ-regeltreu ist immer besser. Im Schulaufsatz: Hier genießt der Kultusminister des jeweiligen Bundeslandes seine großherrschaftliche Machtvollkommenheit.